# База данных в CRM приложении

Tags: java, android

Я начинающий разработчик. У меня вот такой вопрос. Как создать учётные записи руководителей и менеджеров и взаимодействие между ними? Я так понимаю для этого  необходимо сделать базу данных на сервере. Я слышал о firebase, можно ли с помощью этой технологии сделал нормальное CRM приложение? Или это как то по другому можно сделать? (сроки маленькие)

Comment: Именно базу данных и нужно сделать. В Firebase есть возможность создать БД, но это не единственный способ. За основу вы можете взять любую СУБД, коих достаточно. Вопрос в другом, что в любом случае, для взаимодействия с БД, клиентами и т.д. нужен backend (серверная часть вашего приложения).

Comment: Начинать никогда не поздно, поздно не начинать. На до конкретно указать с какой CRM будешь работать, создавать собственную кажется невозможным.

Comment: На вашем случае, я предлагаю использовать Firebase. Так как он удобный и понятны и еще бесплатны.